# Need assistance, trying to fix an error in python

Tags: python, random

I wrote a program to simulate a match between teams and print the score and the points, on first glance, it seems its working but every once in a while, maybe once out of four times after running it, it doesnt add the points and i dont seem to know whats causing the problem

Nothing i try seems to fix the error. The code:

```
import random

#A list of the parameters for the teams and their actions
action=['teamplay1','yellow','red','teamplay2']
teamplay1=['score','defence','almost','offside','var']
teamplay2=['score','defence','almost','offside','var']
teams=['Chelsea','Arsenal','Barcelona','Madrid']

#Setting the intial value of the score and point to zero
global score1,score2
score1=0
score2=0
point1=0
point2=0

#selecting the teams and making sure that it doesnt select the same team twice
a=random.choice(teams)
teams.remove(a)
b=random.choice(teams)

   
#defining the choices for the action list and printing relevant text based on the random choice
def action_choices():
 global score1,score2
 x=random.choice(action)
 if x =='teamplay1':
    y=random.choice(teamplay1)
    if y == 'score':
        print(a + ' scores')
        #To add the goal to the score of the team
        score1=score1+1

    elif y == 'defence':
        print('Good defence by ' + a + ', they broke down the ' + b + ' attack')

    elif y == 'almost':
        print(a +  ' almost scored')

    elif y == 'offside':
        print(a +  ' are offside')

    elif y == 'var':
        print(a + "'s goal is ruled out by offside")

    else:
        print('ERROR')

 elif x =='teamplay2':
    y=random.choice(teamplay2)
    if y == 'score':
        print(b + ' scores')
        #To add the goal to the score of the team
        score2=score2+1

    elif y == 'defence':
        print('Good defence by ' + b + ', they broke down the ' + a + ' attack')

    elif y == 'almost':
        print(b +  ' almost scored')

    elif y == 'offside':
        print(b +  ' are offside')

    elif y == 'var':
        print(b + "'s goal is ruled out by offside")

    else:
        print('ERROR')

 elif x=='yellow':
    z=random.choice(teams)
    print('Yellow card for '+ z)

 elif x=='red':
    z=random.choice(teams)
    print('Red card for '+ z)

#defining the clock for the match and printing the scores of both teams    
def process(clock=0):
    print('Minute ' + str(clock) + ' : ')
    action_choices()
    clock=clock+10
    if clock==90:
        print('Match is over.')
        print(a + ' : ' + str(score1) + ' ' + b + ' : ' + str(score2))
    else:
        process(clock)

#creating a function to calculate the points for the teams based on whether they won, drew or lost and printing them out
def add_point():
 global point1, point2
 if score1>score2:
    point1=point1 + 3

 elif score1==score2:
    point1=point1 + 1
    point2=point2 + 1

 elif point2>point1:
    point2=point2 + 3

 else:
    print('Error')
 print(a + ' points : ' + str(point1) + ' ' + b + ' points : ' + str(point2))

#playing the match
def play():
    print("Today's match is between " + a + " and " + b)
    process()
    add_point()
    
    
play()
```

Comment: What happens when it "doesn't add points"?

Comment: What is the error? [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: You are comparing `points` instead of `scores`. in 2nd elif clause.

Comment: This is a cute project.. a bit off-topic but after you get this single-match version working, to start keeping track of the points of each team across a series of games I would suggest using a dictionary (just google python dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code seems to be in the add_point() function. The problem is that you are checking if point2 is greater than point1 and if so, you are incrementing point2 by 3. However, you are not checking if point2 is greater than point1 in the first place. This condition will never be true because point2 and point1 are both initialized to 0 and are not changed until the add_point() function is called.
Here is the corrected add_point() function:

```
def add_point():
    global point1, point2
if score1 > score2:
    point1 = point1 + 3
elif score1 == score2:
    point1 = point1 + 1
    point2 = point2 + 1
elif score2 > score1:
    point2 = point2 + 3
else:
    print('Error')
print(a + ' points : ' + str(point1) + ' ' + b + ' points : ' + str(point2))
```

Comment: You don't need to test `score2 > score1` (at that point, it can't be false), and *definitely* don't need the `else`/`Error`.

Comment: This can be boiled down to typo comparing `points` instead of `scores`.

Comment: @ScottHunter You are correct, I just modified the code to work without looking into it, but it those should be omitted.

Comment: Actually @matszwecja suggestion is even better.

`def add_point():
    global point1, point2

    if point1 > point2:
        point1 += 3
    elif point2 > point1:
        point2 += 3
    else:
        point1 += 1
        point2 += 1`

Comment: @zjalicf no, it **should** compare scores in all places. OPs code compared scores first 2 times and then points.